# All row sum with pandas except one

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, numpy

I have several tables on a PostgreSQL database that look more or less like that:

```
gid      col2       col1        col3
6        15         45          77
1        15         45          57
2        14         0.2         42
3        12         6           37
4        9          85          27
5        5          1           15
```

For each table, numbers and columns' names change (I created them in a loop in python).

I would like to have back another column called sum for each table with the sum of each calumn except for the gid. The goal is having something like that:

```
gid     col2       col1        col3     sum 
6        15         45          77      137
1        15         45          57      117
2        14         0.2         42      56.2
3        12         6           37      55
4        9          85          27      121 
5        5          1           15      21
```

I cannot use column name: the only one with no changes is `gid`.

Some idea to make it with `python` (`pandas`, `numpy`) or `psql`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df['sum'] = df.drop('gid', axis=1).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   gid  col2  col1  col3    sum
0    6    15  45.0    77  137.0
1    1    15  45.0    57  117.0
2    2    14   0.2    42   56.2
3    3    12   6.0    37   55.0
4    4     9  85.0    27  121.0
5    5     5   1.0    15   21.0
```

If `gid` is always first column, select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) all columns without first and then `sum` them:

```
df['sum'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   gid  col2  col1  col3    sum
0    6    15  45.0    77  137.0
1    1    15  45.0    57  117.0
2    2    14   0.2    42   56.2
3    3    12   6.0    37   55.0
4    4     9  85.0    27  121.0
5    5     5   1.0    15   21.0
```

Comment: I never would have though of using drop here.  That is such an elegant solution.

Comment: @tnknepp - Thank you.

Comment: what if the sum is per column and will be appended on axis 0? but the length will not be match since gid is excluded. is it possible?