# Compute sum of rows in a new column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as follow, where the column length can increase a lot. I am looking to create a new column based on the sum of each row

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        A            |         B        |         C        |      Total       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        x            |         34       |         8        |        42        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        y            |         43       |        12        |        55        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        z            |         6        |         321      |        327       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I know I can easily do: `df['Total'] = df['B'] + df['C']`
However I am looking for a better technique as my column length can be very more important

Comment: `df['Total'] = df['B'] + df['C']`?

Comment: As I mentioned I might have dozens of columns

Comment: This may be helpful ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003371/all-row-sum-with-pandas-except-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` could be painfully slow for dataframes with large number of rows. Avoid it whenever possible. Here is a work-around.

```py
cols_to_sum = [<columns to sum over>]
df['Total'] = df[cols_to_sum].sum(axis = 1)
```

Here is a performance comparison between the two methods:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : np.random.randn(100000), 
                   "b": np.random.randn(100000), 
                   "c": np.random.randn(100000), 
                   "d": np.random.randn(100000), 
                   "e": np.random.randn(100000)})
cols_to_sum = list('abcde')

%%time
result1 = df[cols_to_sum].apply(np.sum, axis = 1)
>> CPU times: user 7.88 s, sys: 39.7 ms, total: 7.92 s
>> Wall time: 7.89 s

%%time
result2 = df[cols_to_sum].sum(axis = 1)
>> CPU times: user 9.51 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 9.51 ms
>> Wall time: 17.5 ms

print((result1 == result2).all())
>> True
```

That's ~ 400x speed-up for you.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I guess instead of writing all columns manually in my code I can just do as follow: 
`cols_to_sum = df.columns.values` this will save me a lot of verbosity

Answer (score 3):

You can use apply in the row like this:

```
df['Total'] = df.apply(np.sum, axis=1)
```

If you want to jump the first column, you can use .loc:

```
df['Total'] = df.loc[:, 1:].apply(np.sum, axis=1)
```